# Multiple Instances of the Same UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multiple-instances

**The Problem**

I'm creating a custom UIView, where I need multiple instances of a UIButton. I'm hoping to save memory (and code!) through creating one instance of each button, and then using tags to identify which button is which. I could be creating new 'up' and 'down' buttons, but I'd like to see if I can do this smarter.

The way I have it setup is 3 (*should* work for any number, however) UILabels, with a 'up' and 'down' button below or above each button respectively. I'm also using a count for the CGPoint location of each button, to match up with the corresponding UILabel.

**What I'm doing**

So what I am doing is setting the xCount to the default value, creating the 1st label, and then creating the 1st 'up' and 'down' buttons before adding the label and buttons as subviews.

Next I increase the xCount, and change the tags and set the frame for each the label, and both buttons. However, this moves the once 1st button(s) over to the new frame (as expected).

**What I've tried:**

I've tried setting each button to be a copy of itself after each use (after the 1st label and buttons are added to the subview), but this gives errors upon run.

```
button = [button copy];
```

This is more of a code formatting issue, rather than a problem, but I'm looking for some smarter insight onto the problem :).

This project is using Automatic Reference Counting, if that changes anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

First, your concerns about memory are unfounded. Just create the number of buttons you need.

Second, if you change the frame of a button (or any view), then it moves. You can't have one button in two places.

Third, copying an object uses the same amount of memory as creating two from scratch; new memory has to be allocated for the copy.

Fourth, `UIButton`s don't [conform to `NSCopying`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html), so you can't copy them.

Fifth, your concerns about memory are unfounded. Just create the number of buttons you need.

Comment: Thank, the memory issue was just me being dumb. @stroughtonsmith reccomended I write a method to create the button with different tags and call that method 3 times.